# Apps suddenly stopped starting automatically when my phone boots

Tags: applications, boot

I have two apps that I expect to start when I boot my phone: AccuBattery and Weatherbug. A few months ago though, Weatherbug stopped starting automatically, and AccuBattery stopped a couple days ago. I've been needing to remember to manually start them when I boot my phone, which is a pain.

Neither app lists such a change in functionality in their changelogs, and I haven't done a firmware update that would change how Android functions.

Does anyone know why these apps stopped starting automatically?

Note 8, Android 9

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Android decided to "optimize" the apps for some reason, which apparently had the effect of preventing them from starting automatically.

To fix this,

- Go into Settings
- Search for "Optimize" (click the magnifying glass in the top right)
- Click "Optimize battery usage", then click the option again in the menu that comes up
- In the drop-down at the top, click "All"
- Find your app(s) in the list, and deselect the toggle to the right of it.

The app(s) should now start properly when your phone starts.